# Is there any way of rotating a canvas drawn square seperately?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Just a simple square like this: [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.rect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect)

I want the square to rotate, any angle, and obviously keep the same dimensions.
I will draw multiple squares on the canvas (from 0 to 100+), so I don't think transforming/rotating the canvas will do, since each sqaure has its own angle.
Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: For each rectangle, you can transform, rotate, draw a rect, reset transform, repeat.

Comment: What's wrong with transforming/rotating the canvas?

Comment: How do I rotate a context rectangle? If I rotate the canvas, the whole canvas is rotated to one specific angle, but I have multiple rectangles, with different angles. So I don't get how that would work

Comment: Yes, and if you reset the transform like JohnnyMopp said, the canvas is no longer rotated.

Comment: I see that makes sense. But is rotating a whole canvas each time efficient? or might it be better to draw a rect as line to have it angled

Comment: I think stroking out a path and filling it in later creates more drawing instructions and will take longer.

Comment: Yea fair enough. I know this is highly speculative, but you recon it might be better just to import a small image, 16x16 instead of drawing the same size rect and displaying/rotating those?

Comment: If you can render it at 60 fps on a decently powerful computer, I'd say don't bother trying to optimize it too much. Where it really becomes an issue is when you have several several thousands of objects to render (like when you try to port an old Flash game for example),-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from

- [saving the context's state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save)
- modifying the [transformation matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) (here with `translate` and `rotate` and `scale`)
- drawing a rectangle
- and [restoring the state afterwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore).

Note how the `fillRect` call doesn't need to care about the position and rotation at all.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let hue = 0;
for(let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for(let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(50 + x * 30, 50 + y * 30);
    ctx.rotate(x + y);
    ctx.scale(0.1 + x / 10, 0.1 + y / 10);
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
    ctx.fillRect(-10, -10, 20, 20);
    ctx.restore();
    hue += 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got distracted creating this so it took a little longer than expected. So, just for fun here's 100 animated rotating squares...

```js
let numSquares = 100;
let depth = 4;

class Square {
  static canvasWidth = 0;
  static canvasHeight = 0;

  constructor(canvas, color) {
    // Initialize to random values
    this.angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90);
    this.size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 10
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    this.color = `rgb(${color},${color},${color})`;
    this.xStep = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
    this.yStep = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
    this.rotStep = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
    Square.canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    Square.canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  }
  render(ctx) {
    this.animate();
    // Draw
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.translate(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y));
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * (Math.PI / 180));
    ctx.fillRect(-this.size / 2, -this.size / 2, this.size, this.size);
    ctx.resetTransform();
  }

 // Update animation values for next render
 animate() {
    this.x += this.xStep;
    this.y += this.yStep;
    this.angle = (this.angle + this.rotStep) % 360;
    this.checkOffScreen();
}

  // Change direction if heading off-screen
  checkOffScreen() {
    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > Square.canvasWidth) this.xStep *= -1;
    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > Square.canvasHeight) this.yStep *= -1;
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let squares = [];
const createSquares = (count) => {
  let color = 0;
  const colorStep = 256 / count;
  squares = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    squares.push(new Square(canvas, Math.round(color)));
    color += colorStep;
  }
};
createSquares(numSquares);

// Color gradient for the background
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "red");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#300");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");

const workCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
workCanvas.width = canvas.width;
workCanvas.height = canvas.height;
const workCtx = workCanvas.getContext("2d");

// Render loop
const render = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  workCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  const depthStep = numSquares / depth;
  let df = -1;
  for (let i = numSquares - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    const tempDf = Math.ceil((i+1) / depthStep) - 1;
    if (tempDf != df) {
        df = tempDf;
        workCtx.filter = `blur(${df}px)`;
    }
    squares[numSquares - i - 1].render(workCtx);
  }
  ctx.drawImage(workCanvas, 0, 0);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

const num_sq = document.getElementById("num_sq");
num_sq.value = numSquares;
num_sq.onchange = (e) => {
    numSquares = num_sq.value;
  createSquares(numSquares);
};

const dof = document.getElementById("depth");
dof.value = depth;
dof.onchange = (e) => {
    depth = dof.value;
};
```

```html
<label for="num_sq"># Squares</label>
<input type="number" id="num_sq" min="1" max="500"/>
<label for="depth">Depth of field</label>
<input type="number" id="depth" min="1"/>
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```